# Angularjs Load "$ scope" in a table based on a select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I try to view the "$ scope" in the table to be displayed according to the select chosen. Keeping the default selection in the select.

The $scope that are in the json just a server. example : `" status " : $ scope.DC01_GF1_STATUS "`

Here is modeled : https://plnkr.co/edit/CaWNeIDHe2nFyEgDABvg?p=preview

```
$scope.templates = {"webapp": {
                  "Dc01": [   
                            {
                              "name": "Groupe Froid 1A",
                              "value": "gf1a",
                              "data": {
                                        "status": $scope.DC01_GF1_STATUS,
                                        "capacite": $scope.DC01_GF1_CAP_T
                                      },
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "Groupe Froid 3A",
                              "value": "gf3a",
                              "data": {
                                        "status": $scope.DC01_GF3_STATUS,
                                        "capacite": $scope.DC01_GF3_CAP_T
                                      },
                            }]
                 }
 };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some data. You'll need to import it.

Here's an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/NPfRM0

relevant code:

```
  //  loading dummy status codes:
  $scope.DC01_GF1_STATUS = 'status GF1'
  $scope.DC02_GF1_STATUS = 'status GF2'
  $scope.DC01_GF1_CAP_T = 10
  $scope.DC02_GF1_CAP_T = 5

...

  $scope.testBat = function(arg) {
...
    $scope.capacite = $scope.templates.webapp[arg][0].data.capacite;
    $scope.status = $scope.templates.webapp[arg][0].data.status;
...
  }
```

#### index.html change

```
  <p class="gfInterface">{{capacite}} %</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it works for the first selection. would have [0], [1], [2] etc .. the number increments. But I can not find the way to do it. To load the data based on the selection in the select.

Comment: It will work for each STATUS and CAP_T variable you set. If you look at your template, you are assigning raw properites of `$scope` as capacity and status.. that data has to come from somewhere.
If that data should come from the lcient (ie, real data will be imported and template is just an example), you'll likely find that in place of  the scope variables there is just a text field like `DC01_GF1_STATUS`. An additional query might be necessary to get that status, or it might be a constant that is already defined. You will import data probably with REST api calls, using `$http.get` or similar

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from the declaration of the "$scope". The problem comes when I select a title in the "select" for example "Groupe Froid 3A" values "$scope" name, capacite and status does not change. Because the $scope of such name is `$scope.name = $scope.templates.webapp[building][0].name;` but for the selection "Groupe Froid 3A" the $scope should be `$scope.name = $scope.templates.webapp[building][1].name;`. And it is like for the rest. I would have come to retrieve the id or the value of intitullé selected to generate the $scope.name example. As for building variable `$scope.templates.webapp[building][number].name`. The variable retrieves the id of the selection.